# retrieve users information from facebook

Tags: facebook, passwords

i'm a newbie at this and i'm aware of Facebook connect. but is there an API that allows me to accept a user's USERNAME and PASSWORD? I develop with ASP.NET/C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and there never will be; it's a bad security practice to ask users to provide their login information for another site. API keys and indirect login tokens are far better for inter-site login schemes, which is why Facebook uses it (via Connect).

Answer (score 0):

Due to Facebook's privacy policy, 3rd parties are not able to obtain sensitive information, such as email and password of the user. Facebook does not have a "username" but instead you may fetch the real name of the user, or the name that the user has chosen to show publicly.

This applies to all platform regardless of whether FBJS, C#, PHP, Java...